# Differentiating using Cauchy's repeated integral formula

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, fractional-calculus

Can we use Cauchy's repeated integral formula to differentiate functions?

$$(I^nf)(t)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_a^x (x-t)^{n-1}\space f(t)\space\space dt,\space\space n\notin \mathbb Z_{\leqslant 0}$$

If we replace $n$ with $-n$ such that $0<n<1$, do we end up finding $n$-th derivative of $f(t)$?

I tried to evaluate this equation by trying to find half derivative of $x$, but the integral diverged so I didn't success. Can we use this to differentiate functions and how is it applied on $f(t)=t$

Comment: This is probably the most natural interpretation of fractional derivatives. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating half derivative of $x$ using Cauchy's repeated integral formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574056/calculating-half-derivative-of-x-using-cauchys-repeated-integral-formula)

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Could you please explain as an answer with or without reference to Riemann–Liouville's work? It is not very clear for me to understand.