Semigroup property Fractional Differentiation
I was recently reading over a blog post where the author came to the conclusion that:
$$\frac{d^{a}}{dx^{a}}\left(\frac{d^{b}}{dx^{b}}\right) =
\frac{d^{a+b}}{dx^{a+b}}$$ does not always hold, by considering the half-derivative of $x^{-1/2}$, as
$$D^{1/2}x^{-1/2}=0,\quad \frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}}\left(\frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}}\right)
x^{-1/2} = \frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}}0 = 0 \neq \frac{d}{dx}x^{-1/2}.$$
However, in the wikipedia page I saw it was written about the semi-group property of fractional differintegration $${\frac {d}{dx}}I^{\alpha +1}f(x)=I^{\alpha }f(x),\quad I^{\alpha }(I^{\beta }f)=I^{\alpha +\beta }f,$$
Since this rule seems to work for fractional integration, shouldn't it also work for fractional differentiation, given that:
$$D^\alpha = I^{-\alpha}, \quad D^{\alpha}(D^{\beta}f)=I^{-\alpha}(I^{-\beta}f)=I^{-\alpha -\beta }f=D^{\alpha +\beta}f$$
Does this property hold true, or is it wrong for fractional differentiation?

Why do you think the semiderivative of $x^{-1/2}$ is zero?  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3579292/123905

Using the idea: $$\mathrm{D}^n x^k = \dfrac{k!}{(k-n)!}x^{k-n}=\dfrac{\Pi(k)}{\Pi(k-n)}x^{k-n}$$, plugging in n=1/2 and k=-1/2, the fraction becomes $\Pi(-1/2)/\Pi(-1)=0$.  Alternatively, from https://nrich.maths.org/articles/fractional-calculus-iii  $$\begin{eqnarray} \
\frac{d^{\frac{1}{2}}}{dx^{\frac{1}{2}}} &=& \frac{d}{dx}
\left( \frac{1}{\Gamma (\frac{1}{2})} \int_0^x (x-t)^{-\frac{1}{2}}
t^{-\frac{1}{2}} dt \right) \ &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \int_0^1 (1-u)^{-\frac{1}{2}}u^{-\frac{1}{2}}
du \right) & (t=xu) \ &=& 0 \end{eqnarray}$$
